# how to code the front end client socket code for a browser if my server side socket is in python

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have coded up socket code for the server side in python.

How do I code the client-socket code for a browser ?

Comment: You need to ask something more specific, i.e. a question that is answerable here. If you have a server that is pure sockets (not WebSockets), you can bridge to it using [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify). And there are lots of examples online of WebSocket programming in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you use standart WebSocket on the server, then you may use any standart WebSocket on the client side.
For example, here is [how to make a WebSocket client with jquery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/)